# How to programmatically set (using GET SET property) "httpRuntime maxRequestLength" in ASP.NET with C# as code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, code-behind, httpruntime

How to programmatically set (using GET SET property) "httpRuntime maxRequestLength"  in ASP.NET with C# as code behind

is there any way to set values in `web.config` through C# ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set it in the `web.config`

Just set it in the `web.config` under the `<system.web>` section. In the below example I am setting the `maximum length` to `2GB`

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="600" />
```

Please note that the `maxRequestLength` is set in `KB's` and it can be set up to 2GB (`2079152 KB's`). But default file size limit is `(4MB)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the web.config's [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property in code like this:

```
Configuration webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration( "~" );
var section = (System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup)webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.web");
section.HttpRuntime.MaxRequestLength = 10 * 1024; // 10 MB
webConfig.Save();
```

We do [this exact thing](https://github.com/SparkDevNetwork/Rock/blob/1.0.8/RockWeb/Blocks/Administration/SystemConfiguration.ascx.cs#L120) in our [Rock RMS](https://github.com/SparkDevNetwork/Rock/wiki) content management system.